# Open a custom file in Python

Tags: python, file

could I know how I could open a custom file that has the extension of `.x`, in Python?
I know this: `open()`. However, I want it to do it the way the Document Editors open the `.docx` files.

Comment: You need to use a library that knows how to parse this type of document.

Comment: Oh, but this type of extension is only going to be used for my app.

Comment: Then just open the file with `open("filename.x")`. Python doesn't care about extensions. Your application processes the contents.

Comment: But I want the app to open with the file's content whenever the file is being clicked.

Comment: You mean that when you click on the file in Windows Explorer, you want it to run your Python script?

Comment: Yes, that is it.

Comment: That's a question better asked on [su], how to associate a Python script with an extension.

Comment: Oh, thank you. Will try.